# Changing and saving mysql user data within a view Table which displays a user's data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, input, html-table

I have a table which displays user-data fetched from a mysql table.i want to make it editable right within the cells of this table. I have used php to show data inside "text" type input fields as shown in the code.

In order to resubmit the changed data, I have wrapped the table row within a form, but the issue is that the form data is not resubmitted. I want to make the user change his details and submit it using "save user data" button which is neither sending data for updation-on-click and nor working as submit button. I tried using onsubmit also. Please help.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SAS User Info
    </title>
    <script>
      function chgform(){
        var frm = document.createElement("FORM");
        var v0 = document.getElementById("ser").value;
        var v1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var v2 = document.getElementById("typo").value;
        var v3 = document.getElementById("email").value;
        frm.ser.value = v0;
        frm.name.value = v1;
        frm.typo.value = v2;
        frm.email.value = v3;
        frm.action='editu.php';
        frm.submit();

      };
    </script>
    <?php
require('connect.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$user = $_POST['userlist'];
$queryU = "SELECT ser, username, user_type, email FROM `user` WHERE username = '$user'";
$listU = $connection->query($queryU);
if ($listU->num_rows > 0){
while($rowu = $listU->fetch_assoc()) {
$s = $rowu['ser'] ;
$u = $rowu['username'] ;
$t = $rowu['user_type'] ;
$e = $rowu['email'] ;
$tt = NULL;
if($t=="Administrator"){$tt = "checked"; $z=NULL;}
else {$z = "checked";}
}
}
else {
$s = $t = $u = $e = 'Nil';
}
}
?>
    <style>
      body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: transparent;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #000;
      }
      input[type=email], input[type=text]{
        background: transparent;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
        border-radius: 2px;
        //color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 4px;
        -webkit-placeholder-color: white;
      }
      .bkg{
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        right: -40px;
        bottom: -40px;
        width: auto;
        background-image: url("main.jpg");
        height: 800px;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
        z-index: 0;
      }
      ::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }
      .grad{
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        right: -40px;
        bottom: -40px;
        width: auto;
        height: 800px;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(20%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(10,10,10,0.65)));
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
      .header{
        position: fixed;
        top: calc(35% - 35px);
        left: calc(32% - 255px);
        z-index: 2;
      }
      .nav{
        position: fixed;
        top: calc(40% - 75px);
        left: calc(25% - 255px);
        height: 250px;
        width: 270px;
        padding: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color:rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5);
      }
      .vuser{
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(40% - 75px);
        left: calc(38% - 90px);
        height: 250px;
        width: 926px;
        padding: 10px;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color:rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5);
      }
      .header div{
        float: left;
        height:auto;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
        font-size: 45px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      input[type=button]{
        width: 260px;
        height: 35px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 2px;
        color: #a18d6c;
        font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 700 ;
        padding: 6px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      input[type=button]:hover, 
      input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover{
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      input[type=button]:active{
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
      input[type=password]:focus,input[type=text]:focus,
      input[type=email]:focus
      {
        border: 15px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
      }
      }
      ::-moz-input-placeholder{
        color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
      }
      .style2 {
        font-weight: bold}
      .style6 {
        font-weight: bold}
      .style8 {
        font-weight: bold}
      .style10 {
        font-weight: bold}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bkg">
    </div>
    <div class="grad">
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <div>SAS
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="nav" id="nav">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="bkp"  onclick="window.location='panel.php'" value="Back to Control Panel">&nbsp;
      <input type="button" id="bkm"  onclick="window.location='index.html'" value="Back to Main">
      <input type="button" id="sub" type="submit" onsubmit="chgform()"  value="Save User Data">
    </div>
    <div class="vuser" id="vuser">
      <table id="tab" width="928" style="opacity: 0.9;" height="250" border="1" bordercolor="#666666" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr align="undefined" valign="top" bgcolor="#2693ff">
          <th height="62" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle" class="style2" scope="col"> 
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;;">&nbsp;
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;;">User Registeration Data
            </p>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
          <th width="35" height="62" align="center" valign="middle" class="style26" scope="col">
            <strong>Ser
            </strong>
          </th>
          <th width="200" align="center" valign="middle" class="style26 style6" scope="col">
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">Username
            </p>
          </th>
          <th width="200" align="center" valign="middle" class="style26 style8" scope="col">
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">User Type
            </p>
          </th>
          <th width="365" align="center" valign="middle" class="style26 style10" scope="col">
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">Email 
            </p>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
          <form name="data" id="data" method="GET" action="editu.php" >
            <th height="59" align="center" valign="middle" id = "ser" name="ser" class="style26" scope="row">
              <?php echo $s ?>
            </th>
            <th align="center" valign="middle" class="style26" scope="row"> 
              <div align="center">
                <input type="text" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;" name="name" id="name" maxlength="15" size="15" pattern="[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{5,15}" value="<?php echo $u ?>" required>
                </input>
            </div>
        </th>
      <th align="left" valign="left" class="style26">
        <input type="radio" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;" name="typo" id="typo" value="<?php echo $t ?>" 
               <?php echo $tt; ?>  required>Administrator
      </radio>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;" name="typo" id="typo" value="<?php echo $t ?>" 
           <?php echo $z; ?>" required>User
    </radio>
  </th>
<th align="center" valign="middle" class="style26">
  <div align="center">
    <input style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;" type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Enter your email" value="<?php echo $e ?>" required>
    </input>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My editu.php is here>>

```
<?php 
require('connect.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
$ser = $_GET['ser'];
$usr = $_GET['name'];
$typ = $_GET['typo'];
$eml = $_GET['email'];
$chg = "UPDATE `user` SET `username` = '$usr' , `usertype` = '$typ' ,         
`email` = '$eml' WHERE `ser` = '$ser' ";
$upd = $connection->query($chg);
header( "refresh:1; url=viewuser.php" );
}
?>
```

Comment: First, there are rules when you create code. One is not to put PHP code in the HTML head. For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710674/writing-php-in-head Second you use POST and Get method when you submit the form? This can't be.

Comment: Sir, I am inert and really don't have much knowledge of those rules as you mentioned above. I would appreciate if you could please enlighten upon those rules. Plus how can I reuse this code according to those rules, please?

Comment: The first rule it's explain in the link. The second, it's a question if you are using the same form to send a post and a get?

Comment: To reuse your code you can do this by using ajax or simple submit the form how you are doing. The advantage of the first is not to refresh the web page, the disadvantage is that you must use "javascript" programming language.

Comment: Ajax sounds cool but unfortunately, I don't have expertise in ajax. Moreso, I wish to handle Mysql using javascript although it is client side.But of course, the client sends the commands.Especially when the client is an administrator.

Comment: ok, for now, I have to use the same stuff. How can I hide PHP whilst it has to share mysql data in an html. Secondly post and get were used for different purposes. post to display the fetched data from server and get to send it locally to another page.

Comment: The ajax method it's not difficult if you have the correct configuration, and another plus you can send messages from the server side. But in the meantime I can give you some help, but first I need to know if you are submitting GET and POST in the same form, or you use another way to send the GET by url.

Comment: Sir, @JoseMarques , I will surely like to learn this via ajax way.Forget about the get and post as these are confusing, so i will resort to POST only.. :)

Comment: I have put a brief explanation and a practical example for you to try to do for yourself. Any doubt, just ask for my help.
Good work! And don't forget to give a score to the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed the job by handling the form submission.However, I appreciate all for at least looking into this question.The errors were: 1. i didnt put the submit in any form tag premises and nor did i handle it using .submit() on click.
2. i was using type of button twice.. a. as "button" b. as "submit"

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax the basic:

- Some basic notions of Server side and client side;
- Ned some basic javascript(jquery) notions;
- And some html and javascript basics.

For the first part:

Server-side programming is writing code that runs on the server, using languages supported by the server (such as Java, PHP, C#; it is possible to write code that executes on the server-side in JavaScript). Client-side programming is writing code that will run on the client, and is done in languages that can be executed by the browser, such as JavaScript, html and css.

For the second:

The ajax it's inportant to declare the jQuery Core.

Example:

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Use the last version jQuery Core.

Have the notion of who the AJAX works.

Ajax works doing this steps:

1. An event occurs in a web page (the page is loaded, a button is clicked)
2. An XMLHttpRequest object is created by JavaScript
3. The XMLHttpRequest object sends a request to a web server
4. The server processes the request
5. The server sends a response back to the web page
6. The response is read by JavaScript
7. Proper action (like page update) is performed by JavaScript

For more Use this link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Configure the Request:

url:

Type: String

Description: A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

data:

Type: PlainObject or String or Array

Description: Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)):

Type: String

Description: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

xml: Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.

html: Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

script: Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, _=[TIMESTAMP], to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.

json: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes 
jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)
jsonp: Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.
text: A plain text string.
multiple, space-separated values: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a JSONP request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML: "jsonp text xml". Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml" will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that, convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.

type (default: 'GET'):

Type: String

Description: The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT"). (version added: 1.9.0)

success:

Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

Description: A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

For more information about configuration use the link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'Json',
        data: {'var1': val_1, 'var2': val_2},
        success: function (response) {
           $('.search-results').html(response);
        }
});
```

PHP:

```
$val = $_POST['var1'];//recive the values from ajax
$val = $_POST['var2'];
...// The code to recive and create html code.
echo json_encode($html);//send values back to the main page.
```

For the third and last part:

- How to call javascript function from html and pass parameter between the two. Use this link: [how to call javascript function from html and pass parameter through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976734/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-html-and-pass-parameter-through-it/43977414#43977414)

A full working exemple:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
<script>
   function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
       var var_1 = 
       $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'Json',
        data: {'q': str},
        success: function (response) {
          if(response.error_state = ""){
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = response.html;
          }
          else{
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = response.response.error_state;
          }
        }
});
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server side PHP (teste.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_POST['q']);
$error_state = "";
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    //die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    $error_state = "<p>"."Could not connect:". mysqli_error($con)."</p>";
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$html = "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $html = $html. "<tr>";
    $html = $html. "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    $html = $html. "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    $html = $html. "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
    $html = $html. "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
    $html = $html. "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    $html = $html. "</tr>";
}
$html = $html. "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode (array(
                    'html'=>$html,
                    'error_state'=>$error_state
));
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any doubt, just ask for my help.

Good work! And don't forget to accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: An O M G work done for me exclusively by you sir! gracias !will surely try.  :)

Comment: I really don't wish to use jquery with ajax. so how to use only javascript and ajax without jquery for the same job as you mentioned above. e.g. fetching search results from a mysql db?

Comment: Use this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp If you have any doubt, just ask for my help.

Comment: I saw that example but they are using GET method whilst I am trying to use POST method with the javascript only, instead of jquery for few reasons.how can I share you my code for checking because I have been unable to do the job.

Comment: For using POST you only have to change this lines in your request 'xmlhttp.open ("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true)'; to  'xhttp.open ("POST", "gethint.php" , true)'; and creat a header for the request something like this 'xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");' for sending the data to the php file 'xhttp.send(r=str);' For more information you give a look to this links https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp